# How to get images from its external storage and play them with Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
Container(
    child: Image.file(File("/source/emulated/0/Nathanael/solo/01.jpg")),
)
```

An error occurs when I try to open my image from my external storage of course I have the required permissions.

The error I encounter is:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following PathNotFoundException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Cannot retrieve length of file, path = '/source/emulated/0/Nathanael/solo/01.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Hi dear all I am a beginner in flutter programming and I try to open from my external storage an image of course knowing the full path but when I try to open it with image.file() which takes in parameter a file I can not do it I do not know if I do it in the right way please help me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Image.file**
To load images from the file system in the target device, you must use Image.file. However, you must first ensure that the app has the proper permissions to access the device’s external storage. Open and edit your project’s AndroidManifest.xml file to request these permissions:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package= "flutter.image.demo">
        <uses-permission android:name = 
            "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
    ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

With the file path, the image can be added into the program code:

```
Image.file(new File('/source/emulated/0/Nathanael/solo/01.jpg'))
```

Note that you must also import the ‘dart:io’ library to use the File class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Image Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter Image Demo'),
        ),
        body: new Container(
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          child: Image.file(
             new File('/source/emulated/0/Nathanael/solo/01.jpg')),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

if above solution doesn't work check below link with permission handler
[permission handlder & example](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-display-image-from-file-examples)

**Another way:**
Handle Permission To access a file in storage, the app needs to have the permission to read storage. Otherwise the user will get a permission error unless the file is located in the app's directory. The easiest way to handle permission is by using a 3rd party package such as `permission_handler`. First, add the package in the dependencies section of `pubspec.yaml`

```
  permission_handler: ^5.1.0+2
```

After running flutter pub get (or click on 'Packages get' in Android Studio), the package can be used by adding this import statement.

```
 import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

**Sample Implementation:**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Woolha.com Flutter Tutorial',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Woolha.com | ImageFile Example'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        ),
        body: FileImageExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FileImageExample extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _FileImageExampleState createState() => _FileImageExampleState();
}

class _FileImageExampleState extends State<FileImageExample> {

  PermissionStatus _permissionStatus;

  initState() {
    super.initState();

        () async {
      _permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.status;

      if (_permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        PermissionStatus permissionStatus= await Permission.storage.request();
        setState(() {
          _permissionStatus = permissionStatus;
        });
      }
    } ();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      return Text('Not granted');
    }

    return Image.file(
      File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.jpg'),
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      color: Colors.red,
      colorBlendMode: BlendMode.saturation,
      //      scale: 4,
      errorBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          Object error,
          StackTrace stackTrace,
          ) {
        print(error);
        print(stackTrace);
        return Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          child: const Center(
            child: const Text('Error load image', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          ),
        );
      },
      frameBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          Widget child,
          int frame,
          bool wasSynchronouslyLoaded,
          ) {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 5),
          ),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
    //    return Image(
    //      image: FileImage(
    //        File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.jpg'),
    //        scale: 4
    //      ),
    //    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you thanks to you I solved my problem using this method